# Creating the OTP Base System for multiple User in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want to do is. I want to create a system in where one user generates a one-time password with a 30 second expiry time. And the second user will put this password on their page and if the password is expired or the password is wrong then the second user does not allow to go further and get an appropriate notification.

What I did,
Store the Password in the database check when the second user does login check the database but I was not able to get notification  properly and optimized way